# How to evaluate $ \lim_{{k\to\infty} {p\to\infty}}\frac{a_{k,p}}{b_{k,p}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Define
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> a_{k,p}=&\sum_{n=1}^{k} (2^{n}-1)\\
> +&\sum_{n=1}^{k}{(2^{2n}-2^n-1)}\\
> +&\sum_{n=1}^{k}{(2^{3n}-2^{2n}-2^n-1)}\\
> +&\sum_{n=1}^{k}{(2^{4n}-2^{3n}-2^{2n}-2^n-1)}\\
> +&...\\
> +&\sum_{n=1}^{k}{(2^{pn}-2^{n(p-1)}-2^{n(p-2)}-...-2^{3n}-2^{2n}-2^n-1)}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> b_{k,p}={\frac14\times{[2^{pk}-2^{k(p-1)}-2^{k(p-2)}-...-2^{3k}-2^{2k}-2^k}]^2}
> $$
>
> How to evaluate
>   $$
> \lim_{{k\to\infty}
> {p\to\infty}}\frac{a_{k,p}}{b_{k,p}}?$$

Comment: One can introduce some notations to make the limit more readable.

Comment: And you certainly want to add some parentheses properly.

Comment: Dear @Jack can you edit for me?

Comment: I was trying to edit it but I'm not sure I understand the expression correctly. First of all, do you mean $(\sum_{n=1}^k2^n)-1$ or $\sum_{n=1}^k(2^n-1)$ in the numerator?

Comment: @Jack second. For all.

Comment: Dear Jack, thank you so much for edit and +1.

Comment: Did you try to sum up the geometric series?

Comment: @miracle173,Jack can you look stephen's solution,please? Is it correct solution for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---- **Direct Proof Using Squeeze Theorem** ----

Using the following simplifications for $a_{k,p}$ and $b_{k,p}$:
$$ a_{k,p}=\sum_{n=1}^k\left[2^{pn}-\sum_{m=1}^{p-2}m2^{(p-1-m)n}-p\right]\!;\ and\ \ b_{k,p}=\frac{1}{4}\left(2^{pk}-\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}2^{nk}\right)^2, $$
one can use the geometric series and basic inequality results to obtain:
$$ \frac{a_{k,p}}{b_{k,p}}=\frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^k\left[2^{pn}-\sum_{m=1}^{p-2}m2^{(p-1-m)n}-p\right]}}{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{4}\left(2^{pk}-\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}2^{nk}\right)^2}}\leq\frac{\displaystyle{4\sum_{n=1}^k2^{pn}}}{\displaystyle{\left(2^{pk}-2^k\frac{2^{k(p-1)}-1}{2^k-1}\right)^2}} $$
$$ \leq\frac{4\cdot\displaystyle{2^p\frac{2^{pk}-1}{2^p-1}}}{\displaystyle{\left(2^{pk}-2^k\frac{2^{k(p-1)}}{2^k-1}\right)^2}}\leq\frac{\displaystyle{4\cdot2^{pk}\frac{1}{1-2^{-p}}}}{\displaystyle{\left(2^{pk}\left(\frac{2^k-2}{2^k-1}\right)\right)^2}}\leq\frac{8\cdot2^{pk}}{\displaystyle{\left(2^{pk}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2}}=\frac{32}{\displaystyle{2^{pk}}}\equiv x_{k,p}. $$
It can easily be shown that $\lim(x_{k,p})=0$. Because $0<\frac{a_{k,p}}{b_{k,p}}\leq x_{k,p}$ for all positive $k,p$, it follows from the Squeeze Theorem that the limit in question is 0.

---- **Originally Proposed Route Using Ratio Test** ----

*This route to arriving at a proof is still workable but requires a lot more effort and scratch paper; it can indeed be shown that $L<1$.*

Perhaps this question can be transformed into a different one using the Ratio Test.  That is, define a new sequence $X$ as the ratio:
$$X=(x_{k,p})\equiv\left(\frac{a_{k+1,p+1}\cdot b_{k,p}}{b_{k+1,p+1}\cdot a_{k,p}}\right).$$
If one can show that $\lim(x_{k,p})=L$ exists and that $0<L<1$, then $\lim\left(\frac{a_{k,p}}{b_{k,p}}\right)=0$.

Comment: I think, in my limit  It must be $L>1$, definetly

Comment: See above for an alternative route to obtaining your answer.  However, if the Ratio Test is used, it will indeed be found that $L<1$ (*not* $L>1$). This requires a fair amount of scratch paper and use of the geometric series to find out however.

Comment: Hmm...You worked hard. I'm reviewing the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_{k,p}$ grows (for large $p$ and $k$) like $2^{k(p-1)}$ and $b_{k,p}$ grows like 
$\frac14 2^{2kp}$ the ratio $\frac{a_{k,p}}{b_{k,p}}$ goes to zero.

Are you sure you meant to have the square in the definition of $b_{k,p}$?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Yes I know finite large number $p$ and $k$ limit equal $0$. but here $p,k-> \infty$

Comment: In that case the limit is in fact zero.  In general, if for fixed $p$ above some $p_0$ the limit of $f(p,k)$ as $k\to\infty$ is $L$, and if for fixed $k$ above some $k_0$ the limit of $f(p,k)$ as $p\to\infty$ is $L$, then the limit as they both go to infinity is$L$.  Here, $L$ is zero.

Comment: It's ok.Finally, Is general limit equal to $1$?